# Animation with changing speed

Tags: c#, wpf

**hello,**
I develop an application in c# and WPF that calculate the time of free fall object. The object represented by ellipse and show the proccess of the object on screen. The application get from the user the initial height, initial speed and the dirction(up or down) of the object. The application calculate by formula the max height of object and current height of object by time (I appand a stopwatch).
I wanted to draw the ellipse every time by the  Canvas.setBotton property. The problem is the ellipse doesn't animated clear. The ellipse "move" in step and doesn't smooth (the move doesn't continuous).
The speed of ellipse change every milisecond, hence I can't use animation of WPF (I use formula that know where exactly the ellipse located). Somebody know what to do? Thank's

Comment: Changing every millisecond will not be smooth as you've got no means to add intermediate positions. You're already at 1000fps and WPF animates typically 60 or less. I would alter the transform.position property rather than margin.bottom too. I believe that is easier to evaluate.

Comment: There are two options. Either you do frame-based animation as described in [How to: Render on a Per Frame Interval Using CompositionTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838(v=vs.110).aspx), or you create a custom animation class as described in [Custom Animations Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970564(v=vs.110).aspx). In either case, you'd have to calculate the current kinematics based on the current time.